# Proving $\left|1-e^{2ik\pi / n}\right|=2\sin \frac{k\pi}{n}$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

> Prove the  identity
> $$\left|1-e^{2ik\pi / n}\right|=2\sin \frac{k\pi}{n}$$
> for $k=1,\ldots,n−1$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm) to format your posts.  To begin with, surround math expressions (including numbers) with `$` signs and use `_` for subscripts.  `$x_1$` comes out as $x_1$.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! The community prefers/expects a question to include something of what the asker know about the problem. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc) This helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already know or using techniques beyond your skill level. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you. An isolated problem statement with no evidence of personal effort tends to give the wrong impression, attracting down- and close-votes.)

Answer (score 4):

$$|1-e^{2ik\pi / n}|=|e^{ik\pi / n}(e^{-ik\pi / n} - e^{ik\pi / n})|$$

$$= |e^{ik\pi / n} \cdot 2i\sin \frac{k\pi}{n}| = 2\sin \frac{k\pi}{n}$$